# How can I keep a batch file going until the opened folder window is closed?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, directory, wait, explorer

I've managed to run batch files using the /WAIT command which loads the program then stays running until a program is closed again. I want to do this but for a folder instead of a program, but when I run the following it closes upon loading the folder contents

start /WAIT explorer.exe "path/name/here"

Could anyone help with how I can alter this to keep the batch file running until I close the folder window?

Comment: Did you first try it without either `start` or `/WAIT`, ```%SystemRoot%\explorer.exe "path\name\here"```. _(Please note that the 'folder' name path seperators should be backward slashes, not forward slashes)_. I think ny first instinct would be to test the command with the `/separate` and `/root` options.

Comment: @Compo `explorer.exe` returns control back to `cmd` immediately and `/wait` does not work for this.

Comment: I really should get myself a computer to try such things, I accept your knowledge on this Gerhard. Dalekcaan1963, does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6156327) help?

Comment: @Compo, sure, without a PC it will be pretty difficult to test. By default, one would expect all/most executables to behave when it comes to handling them from `cmd.exe`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a little help from `PowerShell` by creating a function inside of your `batch-file`. Yes, you can use `PowerShell` only, but I have no idea how much code your current script is and therefore not expecting you to re-write everything in `PowerShell`.

```
@echo off
set "fpath=d:\"

start "" "%fpath%"
call :runps

:try
for /F "delims=" %%i in ('powershell -file "%temp%\get_folders.ps1"') do (
    if /i "%%~i" == "%fp%" timeout /t 1 >null && goto :try
)

::Function
goto :EOF
:runps
echo $shell = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application >"%temp%\get_folders.ps1"
echo $windows = $shell.Windows()>>"%temp%\get_folders.ps1"
echo foreach ($window in $windows) { >> "%temp%\get_folders.ps1"
echo    $fp = $window.Document.Folder.Self.Path >> "%temp%\get_folders.ps1"
echo    Write-Output "$fp" >>"%temp%\get_folders.ps1"
echo } >>"%temp%\get_folders.ps1"
```

The script will open the location you chose, then create the `PowerShell` script in your `%temp%` directory. The for loop will call the `PowerShell` script every 1 second.

The `PowerShell` script will loop through all open folders and simply print them. We catch the exact match using `if` in the batch script, if we find that it is still active, we keep on looping until it no longer finds the folder to be active.

Note, please create all other code above the `::Function` label.

Comment: FYI, if you haven't specifically modified your system to allow PowerShell scripts to run, you'll most likely need to change ```powershell -file ...``` to ```powershell -executionpolicy remotesigned -file ...```.